# Preloaded data fetch from api

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anyone help me how to get preloaded data after hitting apis(button pressed) when navigating to next page . Before navigating to next page how  i can load data of that page. So that i can reduce delay in loading data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Bloc/Cubit to handle those navigation events and implement a Repository (where you're going to do all the requests to API). [Here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) is the Bloc documentation.